# Basic PHP iterations and explode? as well as header

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, explode

```
<?php
   include_once("database.php");
   Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
    if(isset($_GET["files"])){
    $src = explode("+",$src);
     for($i = 0;$i<=count($src);$i++){
       echo "console.log('$src');";
       echo "console.log('$src[$i]');";
       $file = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#','',$src[$i]);
       echo "console.log('You\'ve select $file');";   
      }
     exit();
    }else{
       echo "console.error('No Files were found. Please try again, make sure your request is correct')";
   }
?>
```

I'm trying to create a dynamic JavaScript file, and the consoles are working but my iteration of the `$src` is not working.

**EX:**

```
$_GET["files"]  ===>  file1+file2+file3+file4

url looks like  myfile.php?files=file1+file2+file3+file4
```

So basically I want to split these up into an array by seperating the `+` in the `$_GET` I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to learn this on my own but there is not clear cut documentation that I can find quickly.

**ALSO**

Am I do my `preg_replace` correctly? I want to ensure there is no malicious injection going on

**UPDATE**

```
 if(isset($_GET["files"])){
   $src = explode("+",$_GET["files"]);
   foreach($src as $files){
    $file = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#','',$files);
    echo "console.log('$file');";
   }
  exit();
 }
//Direct Output:
==>You've Selected aweelemtawe

//Output should be:
==>You've Selected awc
==>You've Selected elemt
==>You've Selected awe
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ Try to add `"<script>console.log('$yourvar');</script>"`

Comment: It's already in scripts... `<script src="www.mysite.com/dynamic.php?files=?file1+file2+file3+etc"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For the incorrect usage of explode()**

The following line contains your `explode()` call

```
$src = explode("+",$src);
```

At this stage (using the code example you've posted above) $src will not contain any data to be `explode()`ed. You want to use the `$_GET['files']` value as the parameter

```
$src = explode("+", $_GET['files']);
```

See [the php docs on explode](http://php.net/explode) for more info on how it works.

**For your looping/iteration**

For your loop you may also want to change your loop to check for `$i < count($src)`. If you have `file1+file2+file3+file4` the array will have 4 items at index 0, 1, 2 and 3. You want that statement to read `$i < 4` not `$i <= 4`.

**However...** as @TML suggested, [using foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is preferred over for when directly iterating over an array.

```
foreach(explode('+', $_GET['files']) as $file) 
{ 
  // work with $file here (each one will be an element of the exploded array)
}
```

For the sake of simplifying the example, the above is essentially equivalent to

```
$src = explode('+', $_GET['files']);
foreach($src as $file) 
{ 
  // work with $file here (each one will be an element of the exploded array)
}
```

Comment: I generally recommend using direct iteration via `foreach` instead of manually tracking your index using `for`:

`foreach(explode('+', $_GET['files']) as $file) { ... }`

Comment: Hey thanks guys, and I just looked at my code Alex and boy did I over look that argument  `src=explode('+',$src)` I could of looked harder and saw that I was just tired. I'll accept this after I trial it.

Comment: @EasyBB Based on your update I would check the contents of `$_GET['files']` by adding `var_dump($_GET['files'])` after your `if(isset...` line. It looks as though the explode isn't breaking the string up, causing your unexpected output.

Comment: I had it fixed. for some reason it would still console log everything together, but then when I grabbed info from the dB it worked perfectly fine so not sure why that is it works though. Thanks Alex